# Change Firefox Proxy settings from Python

Tags: python, firefox, proxy, settings, configure

Is there are way to change the Firefox Proxy settings from a Python script?

Comment: why exactly do you wish to do this?

Comment: It is for a program I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can edit the settings saved in the prefs.js file in the Firefox profile directory. Firefox has to be restarted for the settings to take effect, though.

This article details where the profile is stored, depending on the operating system:
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/profiles

Comment: PERFECT! Know of anything like this for Chrome, Safari or Netscape?